# Read ontology into GraphX from rdf model

Tags: java, scala, rdf, jena, owl

i am trying to build a graph based view of uniprot data using Spark (GraphX) by leveraging the owl/RDF format. I am trying to parse the data  using apache jena, but I can't wrap my head around the structure of the rdf file. To better illustrate, here's an example of the type of file I'm trying to process.
http://pastebin.com/iSeGs0RZ

For my needs, i have to store/manipulate for instance
<rdfs:seeAlso rdf:resource="http://purl.uniprot.org/string/9606.ENSP00000418960"/>
By that I need to save the token "seeAlso" and the ?predicate? "http://purl.uniprot.org/string/9606.ENSP00000418960"
while trying to load a model in java/scala print(model) displays most of the information but I can't find a way to extract everything from the file.

This is what i'm using to read in the model:

```
object runner {
  val inputFileName = "dataset/test2.xml"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()

    // use the FileManager to find the input file
    val in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName)
    if (in == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "File: " + inputFileName + " not found")
    }
    model.read(in, "RDF/XML")
    val items = model.listObjects()
    var count = 0
    while (items.hasNext) {
      count += 1
      val node = items.next()
      println(node)
      println("\n\n")
    }
    println(count)
  }
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve this problem by separating the RDF/XML parser and the rest of the code.
**Step 1** parse rdf/xml to n-triple/n-quad
**Step 2** parse n-triple with Spark and dump result as vertex&edge object files